# MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() not returning anything

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql

When I run the following code:

```
query = "select count(*) from table where name = '?name'";
MySqlConnection connection = 
  new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydb"].ToString());
connection.Open();
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query,connection);
command.Parameters.Add("?name", name);
Int32 number = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

`number` is always zero, even when cast to an int.

I have tried converting it to int64, no dice. I have tried `command.Prepare()`.  I have tried using `Convert.ToInt32()` and every other variation.  I have tried just about everything under the sun including quoting verbatim what [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-executescalar) suggests and I get no dice.  Trying to cast the object as an integer, as a long, as an int32, none of this seems to work.  These results are always 0 or cause a MySQL error.

EDIT: Stack overflow will not format that code properly in code tags, i apologize

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for that is because the parameter is enclose with single quote thus making it a string. Remove it and it will work,

```
query = "select count(*) from table where name = @name";
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydb"].ToString());
connection.Open();
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query,connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@name", name);
```

for better code,

- use `using` for proper object disposal
- using `try-catch` block for proper handling of exceptions

code snippet,

```
query = "select count(*) from table where name = @name";
string connString =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydb"].ToString();
using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    using(MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@name", name);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            // other codes
        }
        catch(MySqlException ex)
        {
            // do somthing with the exception
            // don't hide it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to improve my code, i've currently got an issue with too many db connections so that will help a lot.

However when attempting to convert it to an int32 by either a cast or by using Convert.ToInt32() the value of the scalar is still always 0.

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to fix it, I modified the query I sent you for security reasons and accidentally left off a vital second query term.  It was on this term that the problem existed.  Thank you!